Trace button misses in QGIS
I cannot find trace button to activate it.
There is printscreen of my QGIS version and toolbars: snapping and advanced digitising but there is no TRACE button:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lU0iwKQdVwWS18KOFcw2UsLjJRePH9Mg/view?usp=sharing

Please include screenshots in your post instead of adding them as a link. Have you made sure you activated the snapping toolbar under view - toolbars?

You seem to have activated the "snapping options" of your project, but not the toolbar, which you can find under View - Toolbars - Snapping.

Thanks a lot!!!! Solved
